# Monitoring display power events on Windows XP

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp

On Windows only the focused application receives display power events via the [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message (with `wParam` set to `SC_MONITORPOWER`, and `lParam` representing the new power state).

On Windows Vista and later, **any** application can be notified of display power events by calling the [`RegisterPowerSettingNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, using the [`GUID_SESSION_DISPLAY_STATUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh448380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) GUID.

Is there a way to achieve the same result on Windows XP, at application level (i.e not using code running at kernel mode)?

Comment: Drivers receive notification of power events.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm looking for something more straightforward, at application level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is handle `WM_SYSCOMMAND`. Options I can think of:

- Use `SetWindowsHookEx` for this (with `WH_CBT`).
- Inject a DLL into every process which hooks CreateProcess and injects itself into all future processes, essentially hooking the entire system. The aforementioned DLL will then subclass all windows in the current process, and you can handle `WM_SYSMESSAGE` from there.

Comment: @Jonathan Lingle: the `WM_SYSMESSAGE` doesn't exist. Do you mean `WM_SYSCOMMAND`?

Comment: @Lorenzo: yeh, that was a typo. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just handle the message WM_POWERBROADCAST in your WindowProc and once received, call GetSystemPowerStatus?

Comment: No, WM_POWERBROADCAST doesn't notify display power events (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I get a down vote, really?  Have you even tried it?  I searched for a replacement that works on XP and got that from here: http://www.nxtbook.com/nxtbooks/cmp/msdnmag0707/index.php?startid=49

Comment: Sure you got a down vote. Your answer is off topic, I've also explained why: WM_POWERBROADCAST doesn't notify _display_ power events. Have you even read the question? And the link I provided you in my previous comment to your answer?